# How can I solve an equation involving a linear combination of exponential functions?

Tags: equation-solving

Given numerical values of `λ1 = 17.142857` and `λ2 = 16.666667` I would like to find `u` such that

$$F(u)=1+\frac{λ_1}{λ_2  - λ_1} e^{-u⁄λ_1} - \frac{λ_2}{λ_2 - λ_1} e^{-u⁄λ_2} = 0.485$$

Answer (score 12):

It seems you are interested only in real solutions, and you could solve this equation with a basic calculator, nonetheless *Mathematica* is a powerful system which allows to widen your perspecitve.

To get real solutions it's reasonable to plot the underlying expression:

```
With[{λ1 = 17.142857, λ2 = 16.666667}, 
      Plot[1 + λ1/(λ2 - λ1)Exp[-(u/λ1)] - λ2/(λ2 - λ1)Exp[-(u/λ2)] - 0.485,
           {u, -20, 60}]]
```

[image]

Most *MSE* users instantaneously think about numerical solvers like `FindRoot` or `NSolve`, e.g.:

```
With[{λ1 = 17.142857, λ2 = 16.666667}, 
     FindRoot[1 + λ1/(λ2 - λ1)Exp[-(u/λ1)] 
                - λ2/(λ2 - λ1)Exp[-(u/λ2)] - 0.485, {u, #}]]& /@ {-10, 10}
```

> ```
> {{u -> -12.8271}, {u -> 27.5691}}
> ```

This works however I prefer exact methods. One can observe that with prescribed accuracy we have:

```
{λ1, λ2, k} = Rationalize[{17.142857, 16.666667, 0.485}, .000001]
```

> ```
> {120/7, 50/3, 97/200}
> ```

Now we get the exact results:

```
Reduce[1 + λ1/(λ2 - λ1)Exp[-(u/λ1)] 
                - λ2/(λ2 - λ1)Exp[-(u/λ2)]- k == 0, u, Reals]
```

> ```
> u == 600 Log[Root[7000 - 7200 #1 + 103 #1^36 &, 1]] || 
> u == 600 Log[Root[7000 - 7200 #1 + 103 #1^36 &, 2]]
> ```

It may be evaluated with an arbitrary precission

```
N[%, 40]
```

> ```
> u == -12.82713340720188515759308715408230827713 ||
> u == 27.56912012244770089901592933324731975534
> ```

Numerically one can solve this equation with any calculator (or strenuously plot on a sheet of paper the underlying function figuring out approximately solutions), however having symbolic functionality it is easier to find out what lies out of the real domain. It appears there are infinitely many solutions:

```
Reduce[1 + λ1/(λ2 - λ1)Exp[-(u/λ1)] 
                - λ2/(λ2 - λ1)Exp[-(u/λ2)]- k == 0, u]
```

Before we show a subset of all complex solutions let's simplify the equation:

```
FullSimplify[1 + λ1/(λ2 - λ1)Exp[-(u/λ1)] 
                - λ2/(λ2 - λ1)Exp[-(u/λ2)]- k == 0]
```

> ```
> E^(-u/600) (7000 + 103 E^(3 u/50)) == 7200
> ```

Thus we have  `7000 + 103 x^36 - 7200 x == 0` with `E^(u/600) == x`. The first equation has `36` solutions (fundamental theorem of algebra) while there correspond to any of them infinitely many solutions of the second equation.

```
(x /. Solve[7000 + 103 x^36 - 7200 x == 0 , x]) == 
 Table[ Root[7000 - 7200 #1 + 103 #1^36 &, k], {k, 36}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

We show all `36` (complex) solutions (`2` of them are real) to the first equation (`7000 + 103 x^36 - 7200 x == 0`):

```
ptsp = ReIm@Table[Root[7000 - 7200 #1 + 103 #1^36 &, k], {k, 36}];
Show[ ListPlot[ ptsp, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.014], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
                AspectRatio -> Automatic],
      Graphics[Circle[]]]
```

[image]

and a subset of all complex solutions to the original equation:

```
pts = Table[ ReIm[600 (2 I Pi n + Log[Root[7000 - 7200 #1 + 103 #1^36 &, k]])],
             {k, 36}, {n, -2, 2}];

ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.011], PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

This should make you more curious about the **symbolic power** of the system.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!

Comment: λ1 = 17.142857 and λ2 = 16.666667 what will be 'u' such that

F(u)=1+λ1/(λ2 - λ1 ) e^(- u ⁄ λ1 ) - λ2/(λ2 - λ1 ) e^(- u ⁄ λ_2 )=0.485 Pls just provide me how to solve this normally by using a calculator.

Comment: Your question asked about solving your equation in _Mathematica_, explaining how to solve it using any calculator  is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: @MadhuThummoju what do you mean by ‘using a calculator’? This seems like a very sufficient answer: The equation was solved using a 'calculator', i.e. Mathematica, *and* it was reduced to an irreducible degree 36 polynomial, which shows how far hand calculations can be taken. What more could there be to do within Mathematica?

Comment: ok thanks..! for the help.

Comment: @MadhuThummoju If an answer satisfies your expectations you should accept it (only one answer may be accepted) while every helpful answer should be upvoted ( when your reputation exceeds 15 points).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like `u=27.5691` and `-12.8271`

```
λ1=17.142857
λ2=16.666667
eq=1+λ1/(λ2-λ1) Exp[-u / λ1]-λ2/(λ2-λ1) Exp[-u / λ2]==0.485;
Plot[eq,{u,-50,50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FindRoot[eq,{u,25}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FindRoot[eq,{u,-10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
 NSolve[eq&& -100<u<100,u]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Until now I didn't know that Plot plots implicit equations, thanks for the  hint.

Comment: λ1 = 17.142857 and λ2 = 16.666667 what will be 'u' such that

F(u)=1+λ1/(λ2 - λ1 ) e^(- u ⁄ λ1 ) - λ2/(λ2 - λ1 ) e^(- u ⁄ λ_2 )=0.485 Please just provide me how to solve this normally by using a calculator stepwise procedure needed