# Which function is recommended for exponentiation

Tags: equation-solving

Because when I use `Solve` my answer is not $1/2$

```
Solve[4^(-1 + x) == 1/2, {x}]
```

> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[
>       1 + (2 I [Pi] C[1])/Log[4] - Log[2]/Log[4], 
>       C[1] [Element] Integers]}}

Even using `NSolve` and `FindInstance` do not offer me the right result

Comment: _Mathematica_ yields the correct result. `FullSimplify[
 ConditionalExpression[1 + (2 I \[Pi] C[1])/Log[4] - Log[2]/Log[4], 
  C[1] \[Element] Integers], C[1] == 0]`.   To understand the issue examine thoroughly this answer [How can I solve an equation involving a linear combination of exponential functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167337/how-can-i-solve-an-equation-involving-a-linear-combination-of-exponential-functi/167344#167344)

Comment: Alternatively `Solve[4^(-1 + x) == 1/2, x, Reals]`